# В php доступ к mysql нулевой

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

Есть сервер **ubuntu** и **https** сайт. На страничке **php** подключаюсь к базе данных. На любой запрос ответ **false**. Причем если подключится по **ssh** и выполнить запрос в **mysql**, то всё работает. Что делать?

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost:3306";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "chem";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Not Connected". mysqli_error());
} 

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "<p>Connected successfully</p>";
$sql = "SELECT MAX(ДатаВремя) AS mdt FROM chem.`Установка ценников` WHERE `Установка ценников`.`id-цены` = 105;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if(!$result){
    die("Not Result");
}
if($result){
printf("$result->num_rows=%i\n<br>", $result->num_rows);
}
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo "max(`ДатаВремя`)=".$row["mdt"];
} else {
    echo "0 results</p>";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Возвращает : `Connected successfully` и `Not Result`.

Решение:

```
$conn->query("SET NAMES utf8;");
```

А как без этого работать?

Comment: ну дак почему при подключении вы в состоянии вывести ошибку, а при запросе нет?

Comment: @teran добавил `die("Not Result:" . $mysqli->error);` - выводит пустую строку.

Comment: `$mysqli->sqlstate` - тоже пустая строка.

Comment: $mysqli->errno - код ошибки = 0

Comment: У вас объект соединения с БД - `$conn`, какое `$mysqli`?

Comment: И вот вы все поля в бектики обернули а `ДатаВремя` нет.

Comment: Галочки все перепробовал, нужны только при присутсвии пробела и минуса.

Comment: printf("Версия клиентской библиотеки: %s\n", mysqli_get_client_info()); => mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 2015040 ; а запрос $sql = "SELECT VERSION() as mdt;" ; => 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 , что такое клиент и где он ?

Comment: Спасибо за внимание, нашёл решение. `$conn->query("SET NAMES utf8;");`. Подскажите пожалуйста, как без этого запроса работать?

Answer (score -1):

Вручную нужно настроить кодировку **utf8**: в файле `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
character_set_server = utf8
```

Затем перегрузится :

```
sudo service mysql restart
```